# Writing async/await version of a promise

Tags: javascript, async-await

The code below logs 'hello world' once in a second as expected.

```
function moveOneStep() {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      res(console.log('Hello world!'))
    }, 1000)
  })  
}

async function main() {
  await moveOneStep();
  await moveOneStep();
  await moveOneStep();
  await moveOneStep();
}
```

Considering the `return` value of an `async` function corresponds to what is returned from `resolve` function in promises, why doesn't the code below output the same result, but instead logs all the 'hello world's at once:

```
async function moveOneStepAsync() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    return console.log('Hello world!');
  }, 1000);
}

async function main() {
  await moveOneStepAsync();
  await moveOneStepAsync();
  await moveOneStepAsync();
  await moveOneStepAsync();
}
```

Comment: Your version doesn't return anything, value *or* promise, to wait for.

Comment: Can you please clarify a bit further? Isn't what returned by an async function is inherently a promise? I would appreciate an example.

Comment: Your above comment should be part of the question, as it highlights the crux of the misunderstanding.

Comment: @deceze It is written before my second example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because `setTimeout` does not return promise to `await` it in your `main` function. setTimeout itself executes synchronously. It adds to an event loop the callback that is passed as an argument to execute in time that is mentioned.

Also in this code return of your callback means nothing as callback with be run in 1 sec and the returned value will go nowhere.

`async` keyword tells you that functions returns promise and could have `await`able code in it. So as there is not await in your code it then looks like

```
function moveOneStepAsync() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    return console.log('Hello world!');
  }, 1000);
  return Promise.resolve();
}
```

So your `await` in main will await one event loop tick to go to the next "step"

Read about setTimeout, event loop, and what await expects to understand it more in-depth

Comment: @UğurKaya I hope you understood it a bit

Answer (score 1):

You do not `return` anything to the function, you return back to the internal setTimeout function, and that does not do anything with that value. Calling `setTimeout` does not return a promise, it rather returns a timer immeadiately. And therefore all the `moveOneStepAsync` calls execute immeadiately, the timers get set, and fire after one second.